# Dominant contribution of v = 0 → v = 1 transition in vibrational spectroscopy

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, ir-spectroscopy

Recently I had studied vibrational spectroscopy using the quantum harmonic oscillator model.

After stating the gross selection rule [that vibrational oscillation demands a change in dipole moment for polar molecule] and showing that transitions are possible only between adjacent energy states ($\Delta v = \pm 1$), my professor's notes state that:

> Most of the molecules will populate the lowest energy states, following Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution, the dominant contribution to IR absorption spectra comes from $v = 0 \to v = 1$ transition and is called fundamental transition.

I do not understand the point that '*Most of the molecules will populate the lowest energy states...*'. What does it mean and how does it lead to the conclusion that most of the times a transition of $v = 0 \to v = 1$ will take place?

Comment: A tangential note: the *vibrational quantum number* is commonly denoted with the English letter $v$, not the Greek $\nu$ (nu). The Greek letter $\nu$ is used to refer to a *frequency*; so we can have a transition for which $\Delta E = h\nu$, for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reference should really be to the Boltzmann distribution where the  population is proportional to $\exp(-E_n/(k_\mathrm BT))$  where $E_n$ is the energy of the $n^{th}$ energy level. This shows that the population is greatest when $n$ is small. Also you need to know that absorption is proportional to the population difference between any two levels. As the vibrational frequency is generally a few hundred wavenumbers, or higher, and $k_\mathrm BT$ at room temperature $\approx 210$ wavenumbers you can see that the population of $n= 0$ levels can be very large compared to that when $n\gt 0$.